# How Elastic search 6 works in magento 2.3.1

Tags: magento2.3, indexing, elasticsearch

I have following questions

1. Does the search result page datas are rendering from Elastic search or from Magento, can you explain me briefly?
2. Does the product listing page datas are rendering from Elastic search or from Magento?
3. Can you help me which event or model file is responsible to trigger the default product ES indexing method?
4. Where can I override and customize the default ES index mapping?

It will be more helpful if you answer me the above questions to proceed integrating default ES functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Search results page`(catalogsearch/result/?q=men)` data will be rendering from Elastic Search only. All the products must be indexed before with the Elastic Search.
2. Product listing page data also rendering from Elastic Search only.
3. `Magento\Elasticsearch\Model\Indexer\IndexerHandler.php` - This file responsible for managing the indexes
   `Magento\Elasticsearch\Model\Adapter\ElasticSearch.php` - This file can manage the documents(products)
4. For product ES mapping, `Magento\Elasticsearch\Model\Adapter\BatchDataMapper\ProductDataMapper.php` might be useful.

To implement other data mapping, this interface can be helpful `\Magento\Elasticsearch\Model\Adapter\DataMapperInterface`